# Selenium Webdriver remote setup

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have the selenium-server-standalone.jar running on my local machine, and the tests I want to run compiled on my remote machine, but I have no idea how I make the tests connect to the machine that will run the browser. Any help appreciated.

Update:
On my local machine (the one I will be running the browser on) I ran

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -mode hub
```

on my remote machine (that I will run the tests from) I ran

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role webDriver -hub http://**My ip*:4444
```

my code contains the following:

```
 @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
            DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://**My ip**:4444/wd/hub"),  
            capability);
            baseUrl = "http://phy05:8080";
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
```

I am using Linux and my tests are written in Java

Comment: What language are your selenium tests written in?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing the implicitWait.  Leaving it at the default of 0 is going to give you more typical behavior.  Most people implement a FluentWait such as WebDriverWait to give you longer variable wait times.  Avoid changing it to '20' seconds.

Answer (score 10):

well. That's not a problem. I'd like to share how i resolved this issue.
I got VM (virtual machine) with jdk installed and selenium server running on VM. VM has IP:
192.168.4.52
I connected to it through(RDC-remote desktop connection). Installed needed browser on it(firefox 15). Open browser. Disabled all the updates and other pop ups.

I've got selenium tests pack on my local machine. And I run them on my VM.
Selenium setup is following:

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase;
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class BaseSeleniumTest extends SeleneseTestBase {
    static WebDriver driver;


    @Value("login.base.url")
    private String loginBaseUrl;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void firefoxSetUp() throws MalformedURLException {

//        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.4.52:4444/wd/hub"), capability);


//        driver = new FirefoxDriver();  //for local check

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
    }
    @Before
    public void openFiretox() throws IOException {



        driver.get(propertyKeysLoader("login.base.url"));


    }


    @AfterClass
    public static void closeFirefox(){
        driver.quit();
    }

.....
```

this piece of code will run all the selenium tests  on remote machine.
in the string `driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.4.52:4444/wd/hub"), capability);`
you simply should mention IP of your machine and this should work.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: So is the seleniuim-server run on the machine with the browser or the one with the tests? My tests are run from the command line on a machine I ssh into, and my browser is on my local machine

Comment: in my approach (on the current project) selenium server run on the VM(remote machine) and browser is on VM(remote machine) as well. Test set is on my local machine but I'm gonna to commit it into repository, add task to Hudson-jenkins to take them from repository and run remotely.
Regards

Comment: You can do this by using docker container for Chrome browser.  Refer to http://underthehood.meltwater.com/blog/2016/11/09/using-docker-with-selenium-server-to-run-your-browser-tests/ and https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium