# Is it possible to grant a website permission to open up another browser?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, remote-access

I wrote a program to use selenium to open a few websites, insert data into fields and then navigate to the desired page on each website. Selenium opens chrome on the machine which runs the code. I was wondering if there is a way to deploy the code to a server on the cloud and have selenium open chrome on my machine.

If that’s not possible, is there a way to send the website's current state (on the server) to me so that I can open the website already on the desired page?

Comment: You could install a desktop environment on that server, then VNC into the server. That would give you a graphical view of what selenium is doing. Would that work for you?

Comment: It may be possible to deploy it on a remote server that talks to a private server on your machine which opens a browser. However selenium with chrome and firefox support headless browsers. So it could all be ran on a remote server, without a physical window. Your private machine could then just check the result via ssh when you chose or on a schedule

Comment: Thank you for the replies, another requirement is that I must be able to interact with the websites selenium automated as if I opened them myself.

Comment: Yes you can do that. See [Remote WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/remote_webdriver/). There're plenty of resources for that topic on Internet. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836114/selenium-webdriver-remote-setup) for example.

Comment: In the Remote WebDriver context, a Remote WebDriver server corresponds to your client machine, and a Remote WebDriver client corresponds to your server on the cloud. So, you may need some kind of port forwarding, such as the SSH remote port forwarding.